# Prevent horizontal scrolling on responsive web app in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

This is driving me bonkers!

I have the following as a hail-mary:

```
.container-fluid, .durandal-wrapper, .page-host, .application-host, .application-host > div, body, html {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important; // still broken if only overflow-x hidden
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}

div {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

^ those are all of my container divs, and then all divs.  I can still take my fat thumb and swipe left into infinity on my web app.  Only on iOS.  I have this in my head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui,width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Well, it's probably something on the site causing the overflow, and that's the root problem you should try to fix. But you could also try replacing all `100%` widths/max-widths with `100vw`

Comment: @MichaelCoker how do I identify the culprit if it only happens on iOS?  PS just tried that - no banana.

Comment: if you can reproduce it using chrome's mobile emulator, use the dev tools. or on a mac you can plug your phone into it and use safari, or you can use the ios simulator in xcode.

Comment: Chrome doesn't repro and I'm on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it was `position: relative` that did the trick.  This black magic is exhausting.

Answer (score -4):

Try using bootstrap, if you are not using it already. There are many formatting videos online, so if you want my personal favorite, it's: LearnCodeAcademy. They created a video on Bootstrap, so you want to check it out.

Comment: Completely irrelevant.